# Connect MSSQL 2014 using python 3.4

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect MSSQL 2014 database using python (3.4).

I installed the pypyodbc package.

```
     import pypyodbc

     connection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER ={SQL Server};' 'SERVER = myserver;' 'UID=user;' 'PWD=password;' 'DATABASE = dbo.db')
```

When I tried this, I'm getting an error saying Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which drivers are installed (in Powershell)

```
Get-ItemProperty 'hklm:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers'
```

Also, Remove the spaces from 'SERVER = myServer' to make 'SERVER=myServer'. For me this works

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myhost;')
```

Comment: What is Powershell. I'm using Windows 7. Do I need to install it to look at the driver? or is there any other way I can find it out?

Also, with `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` I'm getting same error

Comment: Ok I checked on Powershell and SQL Server Native Client 11.0 is installed

`connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};' 'SERVER = myServer;')`

Getting an error msg: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Neither DSN nor SERVER keyword supplied')

Comment: Remove the spaces from 'SERVER = myServer' to make 'SERVER=myServer'